# What should pe POJO for given JSON

Tags: java, json, rest

I am integrating 3rd party REST API.I have written pojo for given json. Form 3rd party I am getting response in form of json as

```
"custom_fields": {
            "Field_68092": {
                "type": "char", 
                "required": true, 
                "value": "1", 
                "label": "orderId"
            }
        }
```

I tried  with following POJO

```
public class Field_68092 {
    private String type;
    private String value;
    private String label;
    private boolean required;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public boolean isRequired() {
        return required;
    }

    public void setRequired(boolean required) {
        this.required = required;
    }
}
```

and custom filed's pojo is

```
public class Custom_fields {
    private Field_68092 Field_68092;

    public Field_68092 getField_68092() {
        return Field_68092;
    }

    public void setField_68092(Field_68092 field_68092) {
        Field_68092 = field_68092;
    }
}
```

Field_68092  every time coming null. can some one help me to find ut what is wrong with POJO structure?

Answer (score 1):

I think nothing wrong with your POJO. Please try with this JSON

```
{"field_68092":{"value":"1","type":"char","label":"orderId","required":true}}
```

Comment: I am using 3rd party rest api so I don't have privilege to modify json structure.

Comment: You can create a simple java project in eclips and add jackson library for test JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Jackson you should use additional annotation

```
@JsonTypeInfo(include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
public class Field_68092 {
```

And custom_fields it is not class name - it is field name inside other class

I check, everything work smoothly

Payment class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;

@JsonTypeInfo(include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
 public class Payment {
     private Field_68092 custom_fields;

     public Field_68092 getCustom_fields() {
         return custom_fields;
    }

    public void setCustom_fields(Field_68092 custom_fields) {
        this.custom_fields = custom_fields;
    }
}
```

Field_68092 class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;

@JsonTypeInfo(include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
    public class Field_68092 {
    private String type;
    private String value;
    private String label;
    private boolean required;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public boolean isRequired() {
        return required;
    }

    public void setRequired(boolean required) {
        this.required = required;
    }
}
```

Simple test:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.StringWriter;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Payment p = new Payment();
        Field_68092 f = new Field_68092();
        f.setLabel("label");
        f.setRequired(false);
        f.setType("type");
        f.setValue("value");
        p.setCustom_fields(f);

        ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
        StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
        m.writer().writeValue(w, p);
        System.out.println(w.getBuffer());
        String json = "{\"Payment\":{\"custom_fields\":{\"Field_68092\":{\"type\":\"type\",\"value\":\"value\",\"label\":\"label\",\"required\":false}}}}";
        Payment p2 = m.readValue(json, Payment.class);
        System.out.println(p2.getCustom_fields());
    }
}
```

Comment: this annotation doesn't work out .  custom_fields is inside another class payment .I put custom_fields  inside payment . Is there any other way to arrange them ?

Comment: What version of Jackson do you use? I have 2.4.1

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.8</version>
        </dependency> this dependency I have defined in my POM.xml

Comment: You should try version 2.x

Comment: please tell your exact version . I will try with that